# Google Docs to bring styles back to toolbar

Tags: google-docs

Today when I wanted to write a new document in Google Docs I saw there seems to be no way to bring back the `Styles` in the top toolbar and the only way was using the menu `Format -> Paragraph Styles`.

Also I see that the `View` menu has very few options and `Paragraph Styles` was not one of them.

Is there a way to see the `styles` back in the top toolbar?